# Reusing Database Connection in GO and 'invalid memory address' errors

Tags: go

I'm new to GO, and can't seem to find any information on an error with reusing a database connection in a global. Here's a simplified version of my code that caues the error:

package main

```
import (
    _ "github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb"
    "database/sql"
)

var debug = flag.Bool("debug", false, "enable debugging")
var password = flag.String("password", "*****", "the database password")
var port *int = flag.Int("port", 1433, "the database port")
var server = flag.String("server", "localhost", "the database server")
var user = flag.String("user", "*****", "the database user")
var db *sql.DB

func main() {
    // Parse the incoming flags to set variables.
    flag.Parse()

    // Output the database variables if the debug flag is set.
    if *debug {
        fmt.Printf(" password:%s\n", *password)
        fmt.Printf(" port:%d\n", *port)
        fmt.Printf(" server:%s\n", *server)
        fmt.Printf(" user:%s\n", *user)
    }

    // Build out the connection string to the database, and then open the connection to the database.
    connString := fmt.Sprintf("server=%s;user id=%s;password=%s;port=%d", *server, *user, *password, *port)
    if *debug { fmt.Printf(" connString:%s\n", connString) }
    db, err := sql.Open("mssql", connString)
    if err != nil { log.Fatal("Open connection failed:", err.Error()) }
    err = db.Ping()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Cannot connect: ", err.Error())
        return
    }

    // Close the connection when we're all done.
    defer db.Close()

    // Truncate the existing records in the ListHubFeed
    res, err := db.Exec( `
        TRUNCATE TABLE foo
    ` )
    _ = res

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println( "TRUNCATE TABLE failed", err )
    }

    eligible := verifyEligibility( "foo" )

}

func verifyEligibility( email string ) ( success bool ) {

    //Run each check individually, and if any one fails, return false and stop processing additional checks

    // if the routing email is bad, then we can't create an account, so kick it out.
    if( !govalidator.IsEmail( email ) ){
        writeToLog( email )
        return false
    }

    return true;

}

func writeToLog( tolog string ) {
    res, err := db.Exec(`
        INSERT INTO Log ( 
            Email
        ) VALUES (
            ?,
            ?,
            ?,
            ?
        )` , tolog )
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println( "insert failed", err )
    }
    _ = res
}
```

That's really ugly psuedocode, but the point is that the `TRUNCATE` statements in `main` run just fine, but after calling `verifyEligibility()` and then attempting to log the entry in the `writeToLog()` function, I get the following error:

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal 0xc0000005 code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x46d485]

goroutine 1 [running]:
database/sql.(*DB).conn(0x0, 0xc082044088, 0x0, 0x0)
        c:/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:634 +0x7b5
database/sql.(*DB).exec(0x0, 0x742730, 0x8, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
        c:/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:884 +0x9d
database/sql.(*DB).Exec(0x0, 0x742730, 0x8, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
        c:/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:875 +0xd4
main.writeToLog(0xc082004a20, 0x11, 0x70f370, 0x5, 0x0, 0x0, 0x777ef0, 0x24, 0x71ba70, 0x3)
```

I can't find any information on this error as it relates to `go-mssqldb`. `db` is declared as a global, and is opened in `main`, so I can't figure out why it's not available to me in `writeToLog()`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your problem is that the `db` pointer is `nil` in the context of your `writeToLog()` function. The culprit is this line:

```
db, err := sql.Open("mssql", connString)
```

Here, you are confusing the short variable declaration operator (`:=`) with the assignment operator (`=`).

This instruction override the `db` global variable with a `db` local variable, only accessible in your `main` function (this is called *shadowing*, and also work with package names, etc). Consequently, the `db` variable used in `writeToLog` is never initialized, hence the `nil pointer dereference` error.

To fix it, you just have to fix your declaration for it to be an affectation:

```
var err error
db, err = sql.Open("mssql", connString)
```

Comment: Looks like I have some more learning to do around variable assignments. You nailed it. Thanks.